# How to get .statuses permission in android 11 later - flutter

Tags: action-open-document-tree

I am done in many ways.

"MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" is not allowed in google console.

"ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE" not fetch the contained video and audio files

I need to get WhatsApp statuses.

```
    private fun checkWhatsAppPermission(waStatusUri: String?) {    
        // val uri = Uri.parse(waStatusUri)
        val waStatusUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses")
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, waStatusUri)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_WHATSAPP_PERMISSION) 
    }

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_WHATSAPP_PERMISSION = 10001
    }
```